# Не выходит форма регистрации

Tags: java, регистрация

я делаю регистрацию для приложения, связал с БД, всё вроде нормально, так же использовал готовое решение от Фейсбука. Суть в чём, при регистрации, приходит СМС код, при вводе которого появляется форма (register_layout), в которой собственно и идёт дальнейшая регистрация, всё работало. Но на следующий день, при всех действиях, форма (register_layout), Просто не появляется, и меня скидывает на начало регистрации. В коде всё чисто, (logcat не сообщает об ошибках).

```
    private void showRegisterDialog(final String phone) {
    final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new 
    AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
alertDialog.setTitle("REGISTER");

LayoutInflater inflater = this.getLayoutInflater();
final View register_layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.register_layout,null);

final MaterialEditText edt_name=(MaterialEditText)register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edt_name);
final MaterialEditText edt_address=(MaterialEditText)register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edt_address);
final MaterialEditText edt_birthdate=(MaterialEditText)register_layout.findViewById(R.id.edt_birthdate);

Button btn_register = (Button)register_layout.findViewById(R.id.btn_register);
edt_birthdate.addTextChangedListener(new PatternedTextWatcher("####-##-##"));
btn_register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        alertDialog.create().dismiss();

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt_address.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter your address", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt_birthdate.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter your birthdate", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(edt_name.getText().toString())) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please enter your name", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            return;
        }

        final AlertDialog watingDialog = new SpotsDialog.Builder().setContext(MainActivity.this).build();
        watingDialog.show();
        watingDialog.setMessage("Please waiting...");

        mService.registerNewUser(phone,
                edt_name.getText().toString(),
                edt_address.getText().toString(),
                edt_birthdate.getText().toString())
                .enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
                        watingDialog.dismiss();
                        User user = response.body();
                        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(user.getError_msg())) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "User register successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
                        watingDialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });

    }




});


alertDialog.setView(register_layout);
alertDialog.show();
```

}

Comment: Вам нужно воспроизвести проблему и выложить [пример кода](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reprex). Без этого мы можем только гадать.

Comment: Если вы говорите, что у вас на следующий день слетает регистрация, возможно, в коде идет привязка даты регистрации к текущему дню. То есть у вас из базы берется не `getRegDay()`, а `getCurrentDay()`, например.

Comment: Нет, после того как получилось в первый раз, я ушёл, запустив снова Андроид студию, больше форма регистрации не появлялась., то есть после первого удачного теста, далее после закрытия студии, форма регистрации больше не появлялась.

Comment: Я решил проблему, проблема заключалась в совместимости двух библиотек ('com.facebook.android:account-kit-sdk:5.+' и 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.0') Не совместима с версией 28.0.0